# Changing Class name, method name and exporting it

Tags: java, android, reflection

Hello I was hoping someone here can help me accomplish this task. I want to change the name of all my field, methods and class in a package (doing it one class at a time will also be fine). I know that even with Java Reflection I won't be able to change it outside the class.

My sample java class :

```
public class Foo {

    private final Object foo = ...
    private Object foo1 = ...

    private void foo(){
       Object foo;
    }

}
```

The generated class should become :

```
public class A{

    private final Object a= ...
    private Object b = ...

    private void a(){
       Object a; //if possible
    }

}
```

It would be great if someone can tell me or give me the code to achieve this, if this can be done on any other language it will also be great. This will obviously be done at the last resort and will only be done to classes that are not activity or, service or any other android file which are referenced outside the package.

Comment: You want to obfuscate your code to protect it ?

Comment: actually you need not to worry your app code always decoded when you release apk

Comment: @Android_Dev did you considered ProGuard?

Comment: @shubhamsharma It's quite easy to decompile an apk (Server sided may be trickier), U will be able to easily see what methods, fields are used and if names are kept as it is it can be quite easy for an attacker to see how it works. If it is like this it will be quite hard to tell whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try proguard, it is free.

You have documentation about how to use it with Android here :
 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Besides, you have many features provided to reduce the size of your APK.

> Code shrinking is available with ProGuard, which detects and removes
>   unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes from your packaged
>   app, including those from included code libraries (making it a
>   valuable tool for working around the 64k reference limit). ProGuard
>   also optimizes the bytecode, removes unused code instructions, and
>   obfuscates the remaining classes, fields, and methods with short
>   names. The obfuscated code makes your APK difficult to reverse
>   engineer, which is especially valuable when your app uses
>   security-sensitive features, such as licensing verification.